# Laravel whereIn query not returning what I need

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have this query:

```
 $postsTags = DB::table('post_tag')->where('tag_id', $id)->get();

      if(count($postsTags) > 0) {
          // Pluck the ID's from a users topics
          $postIDs = $postsTags->pluck('post_id');
          dd($postIDs);
          $posts = Post::whereIn('id', [$postIDs])->get();
      }
```

When I DD $postIDs, I get this:

[image]

I then do my whereIn query, but the problem is it only gives me back one result, not the array of them.

If I do:

```
$postIDs[0]
```

I get 112, but my result should be [111, 112]. So thats not going to work.

Result of `dd($postIDs->all());`

[image]

Comment: You are passing a collection, you need to pass it an array. Either change chain `->toArray()` at the end of your main query or flatten your collection with `->flatten()`

Comment: I have tried doing that, Im not getting it to an array. I might be missing something, can you show me on a query?

Comment: What is the result of `dd($postIDs->all());`

Comment: I added it above in edit

Comment: what about `dd($postIDs->flatten());` ? Actually, you should be able to pass `$postIDs->all()` to the `whereIn` function

Comment: Try this: `$posts = Post::whereIn('id', $postIDs->all())->get();`

Comment: Yes that worked! I will but up the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Angad Dubey said, I had to do this:

```
 $posts = Post::whereIn('id', $postIDs->all())->get();
```

Which gave me back the results I needed.